Manga/manhwa/manhua in which the female protagonist is summoned to a world where no females have ever been born and gains three husbands
The story follows a female protagonist who is summoned to a world where no females have ever been born. In this world, males must summon females from other worlds. Once summoned, the female protagonist starts to gain multiple husbands because, in this world, summoned females can have multiple spouses due to the absence of native females.

Is this Bride of Elysion...?

Ina Yoo, an average girl from earth, gets summoned to a fantasy world called Elysion. Elysion summons females from other worlds and the men of Elysion treat the women with the utmost respect and try to charm the women. When the men of Elysion mate with the women, mana from the men are passed on to the women and the women can use this mana as their own power. Ina is courted by many men of the top hierarchy of Elysion population and her choice affects her political powers in Elysion. As Ina rises in social political status with her increasing magical powers, a rival, Roxanne, appears and tries to overthrow Ina's influence in Elysion by creating riots. Ina now has to calm the riots, but can she do so through her husbands and boyfriends...?


Ina Yoo, a Korean student, was on her way home from university when she woke up on the world of Elysion.
On Elysion, humans are blessed by the stars with strong mana in their bodies, but are all born male, so they use magic to summon women from other worlds in order to marry and have children. The women summoned to Elysion are treated with deference and can have multiple husbands at the same time if they choose.



After arriving on Elysion, Ina is romantically pursued by three noblemen -- Aivian Aestria, Asbellus de Caskal and Kaizer Ilyanis Mikenvorf  -- all of whom eventually become her doting husbands.



You can read the full manhwa at POCKET COMICS.

Yeah that's right, i remember it now thank you!

@Ever Rose - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
